# Tomcat Apache not working on Win7

Tags: tomcat, windows-7

I have installed Tomcat Apache 6.0 onto my system after downloading it from

http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi

using the Windows installer I install the system. But after successful installation the service doesn't start.

Stating an error like follows:

> ```
> Windows could not start the Apache tomcat on Local Computer, 
> For More Information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non microsoft  
> service, contact the service vendor, and refer to the 
> service specific error code   0
> ```

I then try to install the same installer on Win XP and it worked.
Don't know how to resolve this problem and how to get it started on Win7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..
Surprisingly didnt found the right solution over the net...

After two days of headache

the solution is..
from your tomcat/bin location
open the console
and type

java -jar bootstrap.jar

allow any window access if it ask, thats it
check http://localhost:8080/
this was the solution for me
Hope it will help others